# Getting "String index out of range" error when appending to a list (Python)

Tags: python

I'm writing a function to iterate through a column of unstructured recipe ingredients in my dataframe and clean it by removing special characters & formatting each cell into a list of ingredients (right now the cells are formatted as one big string).

As an example, one of the strings looks like this:

`'2½ pounds mixed heirloom tomatoes, cored, sliced ¼-inch thick', '3 tablespoons olive oil', '¾ teaspoon kosher salt, divided, plus more'`

Usually I'd just .split(',') but for some of these strings I need to make sure things like `cored` and `sliced 1/4-inch thick` aren't turned into their own list element and instead are associated with the actual ingredient. For example, in this case I'd want the final list element to be  `2 1/2 pounds mixed heirloom tomatoes cored sliced 1/4-inch thick`).

To do this I've created a function that makes two passes through each string. The first pass cleans up special characters and makes a first version of the list, the second pass evaluates whether each list item should be it's own element or be appended to the previous element in the list.

This is the code:

```
def ingredient_cleanup(cell):
    # creates working list with special characters removed and splitting list elements on commas 
    first_pass = cell.replace("'",'').replace('[','').replace(']','').replace('¼','.25').replace('½','.5').replace('⅓','.33').replace('¾','.75').replace('⅔','.67').lower().strip().split(', ')
    # empty list for final ingredient list
    final_pass = []
    for i in first_pass:
        # if the first element of the string is a number, add to the final ingredient list as-is 
        # note that this will not pick up formatted fractions like ½
        if i[0].isalpha() == False:
            final_pass.append(i)
        # if the first element of the string is a letter, add the string to the last string in the final list 
        else:
        final_pass[-1] = final_pass[-1] + ' ' + i
    return final_pass
```

And then I'm trying to run it using apply:

```
df_rec['ingredients'] = df_rec['ingredients'].apply(ingredient_cleanup)
```

When I run it though I'm getting `IndexError: list index out of range` on the `final_pass.append(i)` portion. I'm not sure how I'm indexing too far on an empty list.

Comment: It happens in the `else` part I am afraid. calling `final_pass[-1]` on an empty list returns said Error.

Answer (score 0):

I think there's typo in your question, you can't get `IndexError` when calling `append` method of `list`. Usually you're getting `IndexError`, when you're trying to index list out of it's range. There's only one such line in your `ingredient_cleanup` function:

```
final_pass[-1] = final_pass[-1] + ' ' + i
```

Error is raised when `final_pass` is empty. Here is fix of `for` loop in your function:

```
for i in first_pass:
    # if the first element of the string is a number, add to the final ingredient list as-is 
    # note that this will not pick up formatted fractions like ½
    if i[0].isalpha() == False:
        final_pass.append(i)
    # if the first element of the string is a letter, add the string to the last string in the final list 
    elif final_pass:
        final_pass[-1] = final_pass[-1] + ' ' + i
    else:
        final_pass.append(i)
```

Btw, i think this function is kind of overkill and you can accomplish your task of splitting string more easily with regexp like this:

```
import re

s = "'2½ pounds mixed heirloom tomatoes, cored, sliced ¼-inch thick', '3 tablespoons olive oil', '¾ teaspoon kosher salt, divided, plus more'"
re.findall(r'\'[^\']*\'', s)
# ["'2½ pounds mixed heirloom tomatoes, cored, sliced ¼-inch thick'", "'3 tablespoons olive oil'", "'¾ teaspoon kosher salt, divided, plus more'"]
```

Answer (score 0):

You should not access an empty list at index [-1] (or any other index):

```
Python 2.7.14 (default, Mar 14 2018, 13:36:31) 
[GCC 7.3.1 20180303 (Red Hat 7.3.1-5)] on linux2
Type "help", "copyright", "credits" or "license" for more information.
>>> l=[]
>>> l[-1]
Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "<stdin>", line 1, in <module>
IndexError: list index out of range
>>>
```

Answer (score 0):

Walking step-by-step with your code (using the supplied input '2½ pounds mixed heirloom tomatoes, cored, sliced ¼-inch thick', '3 tablespoons olive oil', '¾ teaspoon kosher salt, divided, plus more') I receive no errors.

The only difference is that I have the correct indentation after the `else:` statement - which I assume is only an example error.

My output for final_pass is
`['2.5 pounds mixed heirloom tomatoes cored sliced .25-inch thick', '3 tablespoons olive oil', '.75 teaspoon kosher salt divided plus more']

I am guessing there is either more to your code, or you should try and print the line that is actually causing the error. I suspect your else statement may be trying to access the `[-1]` index before anything is in final_pass.